# Unicode character for two *vertical* tildes next to each other? What is that symbol called?

Tags: charts, unicode

Sometimes on graphs, there is a symbol used to indicate a part of the graph has been ellipsed over to make the graph more compact.

It looks something like this: (poor MSPaint mockup)

[image]

1. What is that called?
2. Is there a standard way it's supposed to
   be drawn? (I've seen multiple variations, including just zigzags
   with numerous sharp points)
3. Is there a unicode symbol for it?

The closest I've come to a unicode symbol is just zigzags, and vertical tildes.

Comment: it's drawn by graphing software so I don't think there's a Unicode code point for it, but if in doubt you can check with http://shapecatcher.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. This is typically referred to as a "break" in the axis.
2. The variant you've got is pretty standard. Another variant I've seen simply uses a pair of diagonal lines instead of your "vertical tildes" -- essentially, `--//--`.
3. None that I'm aware of. This notation is not, strictly speaking, a *character* -- it's only used in graphics, not in text -- so it does not have a Unicode codepoint.